# Can a baseball be caught with the non-mitt (no glove) hand?

Tags: rules, baseball

Are there any rules against making a catch with the hand without a mitt? Will the batter still be out?

**Can a baseball be caught with the non-mitt (no glove) hand?**

Comment: To clarify, catch the ball with that hand while it is in flight (a ball that has not yet touched the ground) or otherwise?

Comment: Baseball (and it's rules in general) predates the leather gloves fielders use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> are there any rules against taking a catch with the hand without the Mitt on it?

There are no rules against catching a ball in flight with the hand. See the definition for "catch" below.

> Will the batter still be given out?

Yes. See **Rule 5.09** below.

---

The definition for "catch" can be found in the [2018 MLB Official Baseball Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/documents/0/8/0/268272080/2018_Official_Baseball_Rules.pdf)  (emphasis mine):

> A **CATCH is** the act of a fielder in getting **secure possession in his
>   *hand* or glove of a ball in flight and firmly holding it**; providing he
>   does not use his cap, protector, pocket or any other part of his
>   uniform in getting possession. It is not a catch, however, if
>   simultaneously or immediately following his contact with the ball,
>   he collides with a player, or with a wall, or if he falls down, and as
>   a result of such collision or falling, drops the ball. It is not a
>   catch if a fielder touches a fly ball which then hits a member of the
>   offensive team or an umpire and then is caught by another defensive
>   player. **In establishing the validity of the catch, the fielder shall
>   hold the ball long enough to prove that he has complete control of the
>   ball and that his release of the ball is voluntary and intentional.** If
>   the fielder has made the catch and drops the ball while in the act of
>   making a throw following the catch, the ball shall be adjudged to have
>   been caught.

**Rule 5.09** states:

> A batter is out when -
>
> > (1) His fair or foul fly ball (other than a foul tip) is legally caught by a fielder

Answer (score 8):

not only is it legal, it's been done!

Here's the proof, from 1989, by the San Francisco Giants' Kevin Mitchell:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b_NY5iA3hw

Comment: Sure, it could be done, but how does video proof make it legal? Is there specific verbiage from a rulebook that confirms the legality of such occurence? See [this](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/324/is-it-legal-to-throw-an-alley-oop-to-yourself-in-a-real-game#comment409_327) for more info.

Comment: It was done from 1869 up into the 1890s when players first started introducing gloves.

Comment: The proof that it is legal was that the batter was called out.

Comment: @MarkMonforti Not my point. The question specifically asks, "are there any rules against taking a catch with the hand without the Mitt on it?" This answer provides video proof of said occurrence, but this does not answer the OP's question as stated.

Comment: thus, even I (author of this answer) upvoted the above, accepted answer from @edmastermind29, as that truly answers the question