# Can you make a free throw off the backboard?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

I understand there would be no advantage to do so but was just wondering if it's allowed. Also has it ever happened?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why was my question down voted?

Comment: Not personally opined, but [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239288) may shed some insight.

Comment: I would suspect it's because this happens _all the time_, so it's an odd question to ask the way you did.  Almost any NBA game will involve at least one free throw shot going in off the backboard.  Are you perhaps meaning something else, like going off the edge of the board or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's allowed, and yes it happens. [Here's an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpqTHzvA5DI).

Comment: A [video of such occurrence doesn't necessarily mean it's allowed](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/324/is-it-legal-to-throw-an-alley-oop-to-yourself-in-a-real-game#comment409_327). In this case, you're right, and as an example, it's adequate.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you make a free throw off the backboard? I understand there would be no advantage to do so but was just wondering if it's allowed.

Yes.

> Also has it ever happened?

Yes.

---

**Rule 5 - Section I - a** of the [NBA rule book](http://www.nba.com/.element/mp3/2.0/sect/podcastmp3/NBA/podcast/2013-14-Rule-Book.pdf) states:

> A legal field goal or free throw attempt shall be scored when a ball
>   from the playing area enters the basket from above and remains in or
>   passes through the net

**Rule 4 - Section I - c** states:

> Five sides of the backboard (front, two sides, bottom and top) are
>   considered in play when contacted by the basketball. The back of the backboard and the area directly behind it are out-of-bounds.